# Representing a complex object as a pyqt model class

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt

I'm trying to create a model/view for a complex object in pyqt. All of the examples I have found so far assume the data will be in a repeating element like a table or list. Does anyone know of a good example or tutorial that demonstrates working with something more complicated?

For example lets say I have a class Foo with properties a: int, b: str, and c: bool . I want to display **b** as a text label at the top of the window and **a** and **c** along the left and right side respectively. It doesn't make sense to represent the data for Foo as a list or table. How would I create a model to represent this class? How do I tie that model into the view?

Comment: If you don't want a list or a table (or a tree), you probably don't need a model and a view at all.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What do you mean by "model"? Because, if you mean it in the general assumption of the MVC pattern, then you're confusing it with the Model/View framework used in Qt, which uses *structured data models* that are normally supposed (but not required) to be shown in a view, usually with various columns *or* rows (like a mono-dimensional array, as in lists or tuples) or both (a table in a database) and, possibly, with a 3D ("tree") hierarchy (as in a file system). If you intend *those* kinds of model, then please clarify why you need the model and to what purpose.

Comment: If, instead, you mean "model" in the MVC sense then, as said above, you don't need a Qt model. Just use a custom class and interact with it depending on your needs. Please consider that while the MVC pattern is a solid and perfectly valid concept, it doesn't mean that it *must* be used. As for anything, we use something when it makes sense to use it. I've seen lots of people trying to use MVC (especially in Qt) when it makes absolutely no sense at all, with the result that too often they get an overly convoluted codebase in which they just get lost because it's more complex than it should.

Comment: My primary purpose is to link the fields in the view to the underlying data. If something causes the information in the Foo object to change, I want to push those changes to the view without having to manually refresh all the fields.

Comment: @pbuchheit You must provide a much, *much* more realistic example. A class with a few attributes is trivial to solve using e.g. [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). What ***real*** programming problems have you encountered whilst trying to develop your own solution? SO is not a tutorial site, and asking for recommendation for other such sites is strictly off-topic.